# Unable to input negative sign in EditText created programmatically

Tags: android

I create an EditText programmatically using these lines of code:

```
ContextThemeWrapper mContextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.AppTheme);
EditText mEditText = new EditText(mContextThemeWrapper);
mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
```

The keyboard that shows when I focus on the input is the following:

[image]

However, I am unable to select the "**-**" sign. I've tried pressing once, twice, holding, and the button always inputs a "**.**".

Any ideas on how to input the minus sign before my negative number?

**Edit 1**
Apparently the problem is with the device I need to use. I'm using a Samsung Tablet E with Android 4.4.4.
Testing the same EditText on a different device worked as expected, but I need to run on the tablet.

Comment: How did you create the following keyboard? I mean its style is different from the default one

Comment: @Marat I created it with only the code I added to the question. I am testing on a Samsung Tablet. Not sure if because of being a tablet its layout is a little different, since I can move the keyboard around the screen for this kind of number input. It's my first time developing an app specifically for tablets and not smartphones.

Comment: Did you try to test on other devices and emulator? Cause I have run the code you put into the question and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: @Marat, I did not, but I really need it to run on this specific device for this cliente.
How do you select the - sign? Do you hold it for a moment? Click twice? Or the device you tested the keyboard is completely different and there is no such issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any tablet to test on. But I have run the app on different emulators with different Android versions. I have also tested on my Nexus 5x with Android 7.0 and it worked fine on all of them. I would advice to try on any other emulator/device to know whether the problem is on app or the device os itself

Comment: @Marat thanks for the help. It indeed worked on another device. I created a new app with only an EditText view (created in the layout file) and it did not work on the tablet, but on a Samsung Galaxy Mini it worked normally. 
So I guess now my problem is even bigger, because I need to make it work on the specific tablet that I'm testing on. Any idea better than creating a custom bottom for the negative sign of using the regular keyboard?

Comment: Maybe you could try to clean the cache/memory settings of the keyboard app in Settings -> Apps -> Keyboard? Not sure about any 100% solutions, but I would also look at the keyboard settings. Reset everything to defaults. If any installed, delete all external apps for keyboard or even maybe additional languages. Then switch off and on the tablet.

Comment: @Marat, reseting the keyboard settings to default worked for me. It is really strange, cause the tablet is brand new and I had never changed any keyboard settings, so hadn't even thought about doing so. Would you like to post as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I agree with you. It is really strange. But it happens sometimes. The reason maybe the modified Android by Samsung or some bugs in the Android system itself. But not sure. But anyway I'm glad to hear that you have solved your problem! I will write it as an answer if you don't mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the code you are using is correct and the proof to that is that everything is working fine on other devices. Because the problem is **only** on one device you are testing on the problem seems to be not on the app or code, but on the device itself.

**Solution:** Try resetting keyboard settings or cleaning the cache/memory of keyboard app to restore the factory defaults.